# Moving a domain from a DO account droplet to another DO account droplet

Tags: php, server

I have a DigitalOcean account where I host a domain example.com, now I created another DigitalOcean account and a new droplet and I want to move the domain to my new DO account, do I only have to add the new domain to new account via the DigitalOcean control panel, and removing it from the old one? Or do I have to do other extra stuff? I don't want to be locked out of my domain...

Edit: I'll add some more context, I bought my domain by Godaddy.com, after that I changed godaddy NS to DigitalOcean nameservers, so my next step would be to first remove the DNS records from my first DO account and then add them to my new DO account?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using DigitalOcean's nameservers, since otherwise it would be trivial - just visit your registrar and update the records to point to the new droplet's IP.

Since DigitalOcean uses one global set of nameservers, it isn't possible to add the domain to a second account until it has been removed from the first account. You'll get an error.

Furthermore, some community support questions indicate that the removal isn't immediate, so you might not be able to add the domain on the second account right away. In that case, creating a support ticket should help.

To avoid downtime, you may want to use your registrar's DNS until then - visit the registrar, create all the required records, and switch to using the registrar's nameservers instead of DigitalOcean's. You can then switch back after you have added the domain on the second account.